# Call CMS Block in Non-Checkout KO Template

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, cms-block

I am using the WeltPixel theme and want to add add a CMS block to the ajaxlogin-popup.html file below the "Forgot Password" link.

I am getting this error in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "html: function(){return    
window.checkoutConfig.cms_block_signin_message }"
Message: Cannot read property 'cms_block_signin_message' of undefined
at html (eval at createBindingsStringEvaluator (knockout.js:2982), <anonymous>:3:86)
at update (knockout.js:4371)
at ko.dependentObservable.disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved (knockout.js:3373)
at Function.evaluateImmediate_CallReadThenEndDependencyDetection (knockout.js:2173)
at Function.evaluateImmediate_CallReadWithDependencyDetection (knockout.js:2140)
at Function.evaluateImmediate (knockout.js:2101)
at Object.ko.computed.ko.dependentObservable (knockout.js:1954)
at knockout.js:3371
at Object.arrayForEach (knockout.js:159)
at applyBindingsToNodeInternal (knockout.js:3343)
```

/app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
  <arguments>
     <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
         <item name="cms_block_config_provider" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Model\Checkout\ConfigProvider</item>
     </argument>
  </arguments>
 </type>
</config>
```

/app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Checkout/ConfigProvider.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Checkout;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface;

class ConfigProvider implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
/** @var LayoutInterface  */
protected $_layout;

public function __construct(LayoutInterface $layout)
{
    $this->_layout = $layout;
}

public function getConfig()
{
    $cmsBlockId = 'sign-in-message'; // id of cms block to use

    return [
        // 'cms_block_signin_message' => $this->_layout->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId($cmsBlockId)->toHtml()
        'cms_block_signin_message' => $this->_layout->createBlock(\Magento\Cms\Block\Block::class)
        ->setBlockId($cmsBlockId)->toHtml()
    ];
}
}
```

/app/design/frontend/Vendor/ThemeName/WeltPixel_SocialLogin/web/template/ajaxlogin-popup.html

A portion of the ajaxlogin-popup.html file. My data-bind is at the bottom:

```
<div class="block-content" aria-labelledby="block-customer-login-heading" id="login_section">
        <form class="form form-login"
              method="post"
              data-bind="event: {submit: login }"
              id="ajaxlogin-form">
            <div class="fieldset login" data-bind="attr: {'data-hasrequired': $t('* Required Fields')}">
                <div class="field email required">
                    
                </div>
                <div class="field password required">
                    
                </div>
                <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('additional-login-form-fields') -->
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
                <div class="actions-toolbar">
                    <div class="primary">
                        <button type="submit" class="action login primary" name="send" id="ajaxlogin-send">
                            <span data-bind="i18n: 'Sign In'"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="secondary">
                        <a class="action" data-bind="attr: {href: forgotPasswordUrl}">
                            <span data-bind="i18n: 'Forgot Your Password?'"></span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div data-bind="html: window.checkoutConfig.cms_block_signin_message"></div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

I've looked up several tickets here and help on other sites, but everything is directed toward the Checkout pages. This is not a Checkout page, it is a modal that slides in from the side of the screen. I am going to keep poking around, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Modal]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can declare JS variable in any phtml file and you can use this variable in html file as below**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.cms_block_signin_message = <?php
echo $this->getLayout()
->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')
->setBlockId('sign-in-message') // your cms block identifier as per defined in admin
->toHtml();
?>
</script>
```

**in your html file use below code**

```
<div data-bind="html: window.cms_block_signin_message "></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked after some additional trial and error. I did have to wrap the PHP in the JS in quotes.

Comment: Happy to hear it helped you :) Cheers!!